# Splitting road network into non overlapping segments in QGIS

Tags: qgis, road

I am having a road network shapefile. I want to split it into smaller edges in such a way that each edge consist of two diversions. I am unable to do so.

Here n1, n2 and n3 are any three adjacent points in the road network which are diversions.

I want to convert this road network into a graph.

Image 1: n1-----n2 (desirable output)[image]

Image 2: n1----n2----n3 (overflow condition/ undesirable)[image]

Image 3: n1-----*******n2 (underflow condition/ undesirable)[image]

Comment: I need to break my road network as an ordered set of edges between two points. These edges can be polylines.